# Can I make something opaque if I have set my div opacity down?

Tags: html, css

```
div.body {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100.35%;
    float: center;
    background-color: black;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    -moz-opacity: 0.3;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.3;
    opacity: 0.3;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -1%;
}
```

This is what I have in my main div. I want something in this div to be opaque. Can I do it?

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what you're attempting to do?

Comment: Only if you set the background color to an rgba value instead of setting the opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply opacity to the background by using rgba:

```
div.body {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100.35%;
    float: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);               
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -1%;
}
```

Comment: You're still setting the element opacity here as well as the background opacity...

Comment: @ConorLuddy - sorry, removed the opacity and forgot to remove the vendor prefixed opacity, updated answer

Comment: No prob, but won't that filter: alpha(opacity=30) still affect the whole element in IE?

Answer (score 0):

No, everything within div.body will have a maximum visual opacity of 30% due to the body having same. Giving them opacity of 100% will only make them 30% opaque overall. You would need to apply opacity individually to the elements within instead of applying it to the body.

Edit: if it is only the background of the body that you need to have at 30% opacity, you could use a transparent PNG image or RGBA

Comment: Can I only apply the opacity to the background? That's what I need. :)

Comment: Sure, use: `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3)` (in supporting browsers).

Comment: Yes, do you need to support older versions of IE?

@Xedret has the correct answer if you want to use CSS to do this, however I'm guessing that you need to support older IE as you're using a filter in your original code, so I would suggest that you create a black pixel in your graphics application and give it 30% opacity, then save it as a transparent PNG, and set it as the background image. This will work in all browsers and allow you to remove all of that extra CSS.

Comment: @DavidThomas - 0,0,0,0.3, not 255,255,255, that's white ;)

Comment: Thanks for all of the responses. Didn't think of that. Since I'm not that familiar with rgba.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
div.body {background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);}
```